# How to parse brackets and white space from a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a string on **white space, dictionaries, and tuples**.

Example:

```py
re.findall(<regex>, "foo bar test (1, 2, 3) yes no True False {'a': 1}")
# returns ["foo", "bar", "test", "(1, 2, 3)", "yes", "no", "True", "False", "{"a": 1}"]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Match `\S+` or split on `\s+`.

Comment: This example seems to include converting the matches to various types as part of the matching process. That is not possible. The matches will always be strings, you'll have to convert them to the appropriate type on your own.

Comment: Updated to reflect all strings being returned

Comment: Any guarantees on the contents of the tuples and dictionaries? Could they be arbitrarily nested?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(\([^\)]+\)|\{[^\}]\}|\S+)` seems to work for this.

Comment: Updated string to have white space in the tuples/dicts

Comment: Almost working, its pulling in text after the parenthesis (tuples) though

Comment: Hmm. Seems to work perfectly on regex101.com, at least for the string provided. What result are you seeing?

Comment: @BrettCullen Instead of `\(.+\)`, you may use `\(.+?\)` or (better) `\([^)]+\)`. You should also do the same for `\{.+\}`.

Comment: `'(\(.+?\)|\{.+?\}|\S+)'` ended up working given the regex101 scenario, THANK YOU ALL